# deploy docker image with ansible-container without a docker registy

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-container

I'm trying to use ansible-container to create and deploy my docker application but I can't get it to work.

I have a remote server which I can configure via ansible. On my local machine I'm using ansible-container to build a docker image which is working fine. After running `ansible-container build` I have the docker image on my local machine.
However, I don't get the next step to work. My goal is to push the docker image from my local machine to the remote server and then create and start a docker container based on this image on the remote server.

I'm not using a docker registry. Therefore I'm using the `--local-images` option for `ansible-container deploy` command which prevents it from pushing the image to a registry (at least this is what I understand from the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/reference/deploy.html#cmdoption-ansible-container-deploy-local-images)). This command successfully creates an ansible playbook but when I execute this playbook it still tries to pull the image from the docker.io registry and of course can't find it there.

I think the missing step is to push the local docker image to the remote server but I can't find any hints in the ansible-container docs for this use-case. I have also looked at [ansible docker_image module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_image_module.html) but as far as I understand this is also centered around using a registry.

How can I deploy a docker image to a remote server with ansible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have a docker registry, what you need to do is save the image into a tarball, then upload it to the machine, then import the tarball back into a docker image.

On your local machine save the image into a tarball:

```
docker save --output image.tar <image>
```

Once you upload the tar to the target machine, you can import it back into a docker image using:

```
docker import image.tar <image-name>
```

From there on, the image will be on the machine and docker will not attempt to pull from a registry.